# Special removal of duplicated rows in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

Let's say I have the a data frame `df` as:

```
df<- data.frame(id1=c('A','B','C','D','P'), id2=c('P','H','Q','S','A'),weight=c(3,4,2,7,3))

  id1 id2 weight
1   A   P      3
2   B   H      4
3   C   Q      2
4   D   S      7
5   P   A      3
```

This data frame is the edge list representation of a weighted-undirected graph. In this example, I want to remove either the first row or the last row since they are repeated edges. Of course, I want to do the same with all the repeated edges.

I tried this:

```
w=df[!duplicated(df[,c('id1', 'id2','weight')]),]
```

but this is not enough.

Comment: `df[!duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))), ]`, though there may be a simpler option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pmin/pmax`

```
df[!duplicated(cbind(pmin(df$id1, df$id2), pmax(df$id1, df$id2))),]
#   id1 id2 weight
#1   A   P      3
#2   B   H      4
#3   C   Q      2
#4   D   S      7
```

#### data

```
df<- data.frame(id1=c('A','B','C','D','P'), 
     id2=c('P','H','Q','S','A'),weight=c(3,4,2,7,3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```